How to evaluate $-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{4^n}{\left( (2n+1) \binom{2n}{n} \right)^2} \right) \frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1}$

Question
How to evaluate
$$
-\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\frac{4^{n}}{\left[\rule{0pt}{5mm}
\left(2n + 1\right)\binom{2n}{n}\right]^{2}}\
\frac{H_{n + 1}}{n +1}
$$



My attempt

Due to another shifted sum
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(4x)^n}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}} = \frac{\arcsin(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x(1 - x)}}
$$
with the substitution $xz \to u$ , we have:
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{4^n H_{n+1}}{(n+1)(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}} z^n = - \int_0^z \frac{\arcsin(\sqrt{u})}{\sqrt{u(1-u)}} \log\left(1 - \frac{u}{z}\right)\, \frac{du}{z}
$$
Therefore, by using
$$
\frac{1}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}} = B(n + 1, n + 1),
$$
the generating function above and Fubini's theorem:
$$
-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{4^n}{(2n+1) \binom{2n}{n}} \right)^2 \frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1} 
= -\int_0^1 \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{4^n H_{n+1}}{(n+1)(2n+1) \binom{2n}{n}} (4x(1-x))^n \, dx
$$
$$
= \int_0^1 dx \int_0^{4x(1-x)} \frac{\arcsin(\sqrt{u})}{\sqrt{u(1-u)}} \log\left(1 - \frac{u}{4x(1 - x)}\right) \frac{dx}{4x(1 - x)}
$$
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin\left( \sqrt{u} \right)}{\sqrt{u(1-u)}} \, du \left( \int_{\frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt{1-u}+1)}^{\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{1-u}+1)}  \log\left(1 - \frac{u}{4x(1 - x)}\right) \frac{dx}{4x(1 - x)} \right)
$$
This is what I was able to do. Can someone help me with the last integral?

But do you have $4^{n}$ or $16^{n}$ in the numerator? Because this difference is quite important, since in the second case I think a closed form is possible.

@MarcoCantarini Here’s a refined version:
The $4^n$ is in the numerator because I obtained a sum while integrating a logarithmic integral.
